# error: unexpected unqualified-id before '.' token?

Tags: c++

I have check and recheck the following code, I don't see what the compiler is talking about. I am a novice with c++, so please be detailed!

the code is:

```
//myheader.h:

     #ifndef MYHEADER_H
#define MYHEADER_H


class myHeader
{
    public:
    //mutators
    void setWidth(int);
    void setLength(int);
    //accessors
    int getWidth();
    int getLength();

    myHeader();
    virtual ~myHeader();
private:
    int width,
        length;
};

#endif // MYHEADER_H
```

myheader cpp looks like this:

```
#include "myHeader.h"

myHeader::myHeader()
{
//ctor
  /*  void setWidth(int w);
void setLength(int l);
int getWidth();
int getLength();
*/
}

myHeader::~myHeader()
{
//dtor
}
//setWidth will assign a value to the private member width
void myHeader::setWidth(int w)
{

    width = w;

}
//setLength will assign a value to the private member Length
void myHeader::setLength(int l)
{
    length = l;

}
//getWidth will return the value for the width member
int myHeader::getWidth()
{
return width;

}
//getLength will return the value for the length member
int myHeader::getLength()
{
return length;

}
```

the main is not yet finished, and looks like this:

```
            #include "myHeader.h"
            #include <iostream>

            using namespace std;

            int main()
            {
                myHeader impleHeader;
                int locLength = 0;
                int locWidth = 0;

                cout<<"width / length";
                cin>>locLength>>locWidth;

                myHeader.setLength(locLength);
                myHeader.setWidth(locWidth);

                return 0;
            }
```

I don't see any problem, but a trained eye can definitely spot it. please tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: It would help to know which line the error refers to.

Comment: 'setLength` is an instance member, not a class member.  Thus it cannot be called on `myHeader` .

Comment: Thank you luke, I missed that part.

Comment: for future reference, I think it would be better you to put the log, stack trace, or anything that indicates where the error might be, it's just an idea

Answer (score 2):

`myHeader` is the name of a type, not an object.

You wanted to invoke `setLength()` and `setWidth()` on the object `impleHeader`:

```
                impleHeader.setLength(locLength);
                impleHeader.setWidth(locWidth);
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot....

Thanks for the set of eyes.